# Как можно избежать избытка запятых?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

### Перечитала вчерашний диалог, и, друзья, не воспринимайте всерьёз всё написанное.

Каким образом можно избежать подобного нагромождения запятых без исключения слов в предложении и уместно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запросто.

***Перечитала вчерашний диалог и... друзья, не воспринимайте всерьёз всё написанное.***

Comment: Получается, то, что Вы написали, всё равно считается за одно предложение, так как слово "друзья" пишется с маленькой буквы?

Comment: Да, одно предложение. Многоточие указывает на некую запинку в речи.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!